# How to call static method of a class that has a function with the same name as this class?

Tags: swift, swift3, static, swift4, extension-methods

In my application created with Swift 3.3 I have the following class:

```
class A {

    func A() {

    }
}
```

Now I need to create an extension with a static function and non-static function that calls this static function. I have this draft:

```
extension A {

    static func staticFunc() {

    }

    func f() {

        A.staticFunc()
    }
}
```

However this code is not compilable. How can I fix this problem? I cannot remove or rename `func A`. Migration to Swift 4.1 does not solve the problem.

Comment: You could probably call the static func as `ModuleName.A.staticFunc()` to disambiguate it.  This problem should never happen because functions names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If renaming the function is not possible then a (local) type alias
can be defined as a workaround:

```
extension A {
    typealias AliasA = A

    static func staticFunc() { }

    func f() {
        AliasA.staticFunc()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`type(of: self).staticFunc()` should work. `type(of: self)` takes the type of self and returns it.

Comment: Why should it?  Could you please explain your answer?